# No more wireless connection since hard reboot with wireless connection disabled

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, motherboard

This is the second times it happens to me. Both times, scenario was the same:

- running ubuntu
- wireless connection were disabled
- my computer stopped brutally (no battery or hard reboot)
- when I reboot, there is no wireless connection option anymore (windows and ubuntu)

First time it happened, I had to send my computer to technical service and they changed my motherboard. But I can't believe there isn't an easier solution.

My pc is a DELL inspiron M301z with ubuntu and windows in dual boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected, the answer was easy : the wireless card was disabled in the bios setup.

Hope this will help other people.